# Align two meshes given 2 faces

Tags: rotation, matrix, geometry, webgl, linear-algebra

I have two meshes (A and B) and I know that a triangle in A has the same size and same angles as a triangle in B.

For simplicity, suppose A is an octahedron and B is a tetrahedron. And suppose the triangle in A is the first one and the triangle in B is the first one.

I want to find a way (a matrix) to move B such that the triangle is coincident with the triangle in A.

[image: Octahedron and tetrahedron with one green triangle each]

I'd like to move the blue mesh such as the green triangle touches the green triangle in the orange mesh.

I'd like to move the mesh such so that its triangle's normal will point opposite to that of the stationary mesh's face (so the octahedron and tetrahedron "dock" along the shared face, like pressing two dice together)

I'm using javascript with thee.js, but I'm not tied to any framework or language.

Comment: @DMGregory yes, I'm usign the shiny https://github.com/thi-ng/umbrella for maths, vectors, matrices, and other algorithm... if you don't know it the math signatures for webgl are more or less the same of gl-matrix (https://glmatrix.net/) or regl or stack.gl

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit easier if you have a quaternion "look rotation" method handy, but I don't see one in the library you're using, so I'll describe the algorithm in high level pseudocode and you can translate it as needed. That can include implementing your own `lookRotation(forward, up)`, which returns a quaternion that rotates (0, 0, 1) to point along `forward` and (0, 1, 0) to point as close as possible to `up` using the remaining degree of freedom.

So, we have object 1 with a triangular face ABC and object 2 with a triangular face PQR, each defined in the objects' own local coordinates. We want to move object 2 so that P meets A, Q meets C, and R meets B.

First we'll compute the normal to each face, the centroid of each face, and a vector from the centroid to the vertex we want to match up on each face:

```
n1 = cross(B - A, C - A)
n2 = cross(Q - P, R - P)

c1 = (A + B + C)/3
c2 = (P + Q + R)/3

v1 = A - c1
v2 = P - c2
```

We'll use that to compute an orientation of each face within its object's local coordinate space:

```
q1 = lookRotation(-n1, v1)
q2 = lookRotation(n2, v2)
```

We negate `n1` to flip the face, so we dock object 2 to the outside of the face, not the inside.

Now ABC's orientation in world space is:

```
worldSpaceOrientation = object1.rotation * q1
```

And we can undo the effects of PQR's local orientation by inverting it, to get...

```
object2.rotation = worldSpaceOrientation * q2.inverse
```

Now we've rotated the second object so PRQ is in the right orientation to match ABC, but it's still probably in the wrong position. All we have to do now is get the vector between the two centroids, and translate object 2 by that vector:

```
c1World = object1.matrix * c1
c2World = object2.matrix * c2

object2.position += c2World - c1World
```

Make sure you do this after rotating object 2, otherwise the rotation can change the translation you need, twisting them out of alignment again.

Comment: thanks! I'll try

Comment: what is the difference between `object1.rotation` and `object1.matrix`? does the rotation is encoded into the object matrix?

Comment: The matrix will also include translation and scale.

Comment: so what do you mean with `object2.rotation = worldSpaceOrientation * q2.inverse` ? what is the type of `rotation`? is it a number? a quaternion? a matrix 4x4?

Comment: A quaternion or a matrix can both store a rotation. Which format you use is up to you and does not alter the strategy in any way.